# Can I use a ternary operator in a define as oppose to using an if?

Tags: c++, c, syntax

Suppose I have a macro defined, and I am using that macro within an if else statement

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG(x) {if (x) std::cout << "What is up" << std::endl;}

int main(void) {
  if (true)
    LOG(true);
  else
    false;
  return 0;
}
```

Now this is a tricky case, I realized that depending on the indentation there might be some ambiguity about which 'if' the 'else' should go with.

I have came up with this soultion

```
(some_condition) ? dosomething() : true;
```

This solves the problem, but I am not sure what the repercussion of having a true statement are. Is this a good solution, or is there a better approach?

EDIT: Here is the code that I used, it doesn't work. See if you can fix this?

Comment: Many answers already, but where does the `X` go?

Comment: Why does indentation come into picture here? In the above condition even using the above `macro` if `somebool` is false then not even `else` is executed. It is an  `if-else` with `some_condition` as the controller under an `if` with `somebool` controller. An `else` is associated with its previous most `if` unless there is no separation using scopes.

Comment: There is no ambiguity about the `else`: it goes with the nearest `if` block in the same scope that doesn't already have an `else` block. C++ syntax does **not** depend on indentation.

Comment: That maybe true, but can you look at my edited code example?

Comment: nvm the do while works

Comment: Any reason for not putting an `else` branch with an empty body in the macro?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should define your macro this way:

```
#define LOG(X) do { if (some_condition) dosomething(); } while (0)
```

Comment: Why the `do` / `while`?

Comment: @RichieHindle see here for the rationale http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html

Comment: @RichieHindle: So you can write this : `if(c) LOG(abc); else { etc }`

Comment: Better still, don't use a macro!

Comment: @NeilKirk: Why? In such cases, it helps you to log `__LINE__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__FILE__`, etc while keeping your code clean and concise.

Comment: @Nawaz Why can't you pass them as function parameters?

Comment: I tried using this but still doesn't seem to work :S. Is there something wrong with the ternary operator solution?

Comment: @NeilKirk: I can pass everything, but it feels irritating if I need to write them again and again.

Comment: @Anonymous did you add the `;` in the `LOG(x);` macro call?

Comment: @Nawaz You can define a macro that expands to those parameters. I think that would be safer than something which expands to a statement.

Comment: @Nawaz The problem with macros is that they aren't integrated into the language. The effect is that arguments can unexpectedly be evaluated multiple times, or not at all, depending on how the macro expands its arguments, that macros cannot be put in namespaces, can be invoked in a way where syntactically it would otherwise not be interpreted as a function call. They have their uses, but most of them are better replaced or combined with constants or inline functions.

Comment: @NeilKirk: *"You can define a macro that expands to those parameters."* which is not that different from defining a macro such as `LOG` which internally does that. I don't see any significant difference, except in your case, if you have to write that macro again and again as argument to your `log.write` function.

Comment: @hvd: I understand very well what macro is! :-)

Comment: @Nawaz except we have brace issues, while(0)s and all kinds of nonsense.

Comment: @Nawaz I know you know that. It needed saying anyway. :)

Comment: @NeilKirk: Why `while(0)` is nonsense? Please explain.

Comment: @Nawaz it's trickey to get macros to work. I know it makes sense but it's not the kind of sense I want in my own projects.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Such things are there to help you. If it helps you to improve the rest of your code by making it concise and clean, then I think it is totally justified to use such ugly tricks at one place, rather than passing macros as argument to function used in the entire codebase.

Comment: FYI, The reason I didn't use an inline function was because internally the macro used a printf like function. I needed to pass in variable number of args. For that a macro is better suited then an inline.

Answer (score 5):

Indentation is for the benefit of humans are makes no difference to the compiler. When in doubt, add braces, which I recommend you do all the time.

Macros are (usually) bad. Is there any reason you can't use a function?

If the result of (..?..:..) isn't "used" or "stored" anywhere, the result is just ignored, but the function will still be called. So your code should work fine, although it's bad and confusing style.

Unlike the other answers, I didn't notice the lack of braces in the macro would break the else. But it doesn't matter to me because I'd never use that macro for just that reason!

Comment: Using macros is common for logging or assertion frameworks, because e.g. if your logging `cond` is false, you don't want to do the costly log message building. You can only achieve that with macros. But yes, macros are dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

Preprocessing is textual substitution. You could ask your compiler to give the preprocessed textual form (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use `gcc -C -E`)

Your code is expanded to

```
if (somebool)
  if (some_condition) dosomething();
 else
   somethingelse();
```

so the `else`  apply to the test on `some_condition` , surely not what you want.

The trick is to always expand statement-like macros to `do{`...`}while(0)` e.g.

```
#define LOG(X) do{ if (some_condition) dosomething(); }while(0)
```

<sup>NB: the `while(0)` loop will be optimized away by the compiler!</sup>

Actually, if `X` appears in both `some_condition` and the `dosomething()` you could use GCC extensions, like e.g.

```
#define LOG(X) do {typeof(X) _x=(X); \
                   if (predicate(_x)) handle(_x); }while(0)
```

If `X` is alsways an `int` replace `typeof(X)` by `int`. With C++11, you could use `auto` instead.

This would make `LOG(i++)` macro invocation do something more sensible. (you probably don't want the incrementation to be done twice).

Better yet, avoid macros and use inline functions when possible.

<sup>if working on a huge source code compiled by GCC, you could even customize the `gcc` compiler -e.g. add your own specific builtins or pragmas- with e.g. [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or other GCC plugins, but such an approach requires some work so is worthwhile on big projects only.</sup>

BTW, the [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) preprocessor can be configured and used as a C / C++ preprocessor, and provides more powerful features.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
#define LOG(X) ((some_condition) && dosomething())
```

Here I'm using the lazy evaluation of `&&`: the right part is only evaluated if `some_condition` is true.

Caveat: `dosomething()` may not return `void`, and depending on what it does return, you may need to cast to prevent a compiler warning on `&&`.

On the other hand, your solution using `? :`, is very nice.  There is no problem at all in having an expression with a random value (`true` in your case); the compiler will optimise this away nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the test *inside* your `dosomething()` or wrap it so that it does the test?

I'm assuming this is some kind of logging function you want to remove in certain builds hence the need for a define? If so I would consider writing it, as much as possible, so that it is as  thin a wrapper as possible over the functions you're actually implementing. I would do this:

```
void loggingFunction(x)
{
  if (condition)
    dosomething(x);
  else
    dosummatelse(x);
}

#define LOG(x) loggingFunction(x)
```

This has the added bonus of playing nicely with expressions such as `LOG(x++)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your macro to be usable in a context that requires a *statement*, and it includes any kind of control structure (`for`, `if`, `while`, ...), then you should wrap it in `do { ... } while(0)`. The caller then appends a semicolon, resulting in a loop that executes exactly once. This avoids ambiguities when it's used in an `if`/`else` statement. (See question 10.4 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).)

If you want the macro to be usable in a context that requires an *expression*, you can't use `if/else` (unless you use a language extension like gcc's [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), but that makes your code non-portable). So you can use the ternary conditional operator `?:` instead.

In your case, this:

```
#define LOG(x) {if (x) std::cout << "What is up" << std::endl;}
```

could be written as:

```
#define LOG(x) ( (x) ? (std::cout << "What is up" << std::endl), 0 : 0 )
```

As you can see, this can get complicated. I had to add an arbitrary `0`, since `?:` requires three operands (unlike an `if` statement, where the `else` is optional). I also had to add a comma operator so the second and third operands are type-compatible.

It's probably not worth the effort in this case, since `LOG(...)` will probably only be used in statement context (unless you update the macro so it yields a meaningful result), but it can be a useful technique in general.

Then again, an inline function is probably better.

Comment: Inline function would be pretty good, but I am using variable number of args and passing those to a printf statement within the macro :(